# Improper Integral: Comparison Test

Tags: calculus, limits, improper-integrals

I have the following improper integral:
$$\int ^\infty _{-\infty}\frac{2016}{e^x+e^{-x}} \, dx$$
My question is how to prove that it is convergent or divergent by using the Comparison Test.

Comment: So we have $2016\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sech x\text dx$.  What might you compare to?

Comment: Just for fun, evaluating the integral yields $1008\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Use $\frac{2016}{e^x}$ for the integral from $0$ to $\infty$ and $\frac{2016}{e^{-x}}$ for the integral from $-\infty$ to $0$ to show the convergence due to the majorant-criterion.